# Integrating For Each Loop and MySql Variable Associative Array

Tags: mysql, arrays, variables, for-loop

I have the following line that is part of a for each loop that is looping through an associative array returned from a SQL query. I get this error:

> *Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in.*

The error happens when I use an assigned variable for `$field2`. But if I replace `$field2` with the actual field name in the table which is `county_slug`, it works.

How do I use a variable in the statement below?

```
 echo "<a href='/dealers/3/$geography->$field2/'>$geography->county_short</a>"
```

Comment: Enclose those in `{}` as `{$geography->$field2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Michael Said.

Enclose using `{}` as `{$geography->$field2}`

But you have another error present in your line. You are missing your closing Semi-Colon to end your statement. 
`;`

Your Line Should be as followed:

`echo "<a href='/dealers/3/{$geography->$field2}/'>$geography->county_short</a>";`

Comment: I think you mean `echo "<a href='/dealers/3/{$geography->$field2}/'>$geography->county_short</a>";`.

Comment: Thank you that solve it.  What does the { mean in the statement?